# Ansible condition on dictionary item

Tags: ansible

I have one dictionary list defined:

```
members_list:
          any:
             name: any
             username: any
          anyone:
             name: 
             username: anyone
```

In my Ansible playbook, I am running multiple docker containers:

```
docker_container:
     name: "{{ item.key }}"
when: "{{ item.key }} != any"
with_dict: "{{ members_list }}"
```

But I am getting following error:

```
The conditional check '{{ item.key }} != any' failed. The 
error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ item.key 
}} != any): 'any' is undefined
```

When I run the playbook without when conditional operator it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the word `any`, because otherwise it is interpreted as a variable reference. Also, you *don't* need Jinja templating markers in a `when` expression (the expression is already evaluated as a jinja expression):

```
- docker_container:
       name: "{{ item.key }}"
  when: "item.key != 'any'"
  with_dict: "{{ members_list }}"
```

I find nested quotes like this can be confusing, and often opt for one
of YAMLs alternative quoting mechanisms, e.g.:

```
- docker_container:
       name: "{{ item.key }}"
  when: >-
    item.key != 'any'
  with_dict: "{{ members_list }}"
```

This is identical to the previous version; I just find it easier to
read and understand.